# how get get file name in file chooser in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

could you please tell me how get get file name in file chooser in react ?
I am trying to set value in input field after choosing file from `file chooser`
here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d4kp1d?file=bulk.js
I tried like this

```
<input
        id="file_input_file"
        className="none"
        type="file"
        ref={inputRef }
        onChange={(e)=>{
          console.log('---')
          console.log(inputRef.current[0].files[0].name)

        }}
      />
```

it gives me `undefined`

Comment: Just remove the square brackets from `current`, i.e. `console.log(inputRef.current.files[0].name)`

Comment: @Jayce444 working ..but how to set want in input field because I am not using `setSate` in this component

Comment: @user944513 I added the CodePen for that documentation response I posted, so you can see a runnable example. Select a file then click the submit button.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good documentation and example taken from here, explaining what you are trying to do.
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaXXJj

React.JS contains a specific File API to use.

The following example shows how to create a ref to the DOM node to access file(s) in a submit handler:

> HTML

```
<input type="file" />
```

> React.JS

```
class FileInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.fileInput = React.createRef();
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(
      `Selected file - ${
        this.fileInput.current.files[0].name
      }`
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Upload file:
          <input type="file" ref={this.fileInput} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FileInput />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

> Alert Filename

```
alert(`Selected file - ${this.fileInput.current.files[0].name}`);
```

*Cited: React.JS Documentation | [Examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag)*

Comment: Updated Codepen: https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/uncontrolled-components/input-type-file

Answer (score 9):

You can get selected file name without using `ref`

```
  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(`Selected file - ${event.target.files[0].name}`);
  }

  <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
```

Comment: The op appeared to be or attempting to use a ref though it seems, when the question was asked on March 21, 2019. Also, instead of writing an event handler for every state update, you can use a ref to get form values from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `onChange` handler

```
const changeHandler=(e)=>{
    if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
     let filename = e.target.files[0].name;
      console.log(filename)
    }
  }
<input type="file" onChange={changeHandler}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of useRef, use createRef

and then you can access it by console.log(inputRef.current.files[0].name);

```
import React, { Component, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  FormControl,
  IconButton,
  Input,
  InputAdornment,
  withStyles,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import Attachment from '@material-ui/icons/Attachment';
import CloudDownload from '@material-ui/icons/CloudDownload';
const BulkUpload = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;
  const inputRef = React.createRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        id="file_input_file"
        className="none"
        type="file"
        ref={inputRef}
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log('---');
          console.log(inputRef.current.files[0].name);
        }}
      />
      <Input
        id="adornment-attachment"
        type="text"
        fullWidth
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="Toggle password visibility"
              onClick={(e) => {
                inputRef.current.click();
              }}
              className="login-container__passwordIcon"
            >
              <Attachment />
            </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BulkUpload;
```