# Not able to get absolute filename from onChange event of input type file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So I tried to get the value to chosen file using `e.target.value` but I got the `C:\fakepath` which is understandable.

But now I was trying to get the file name in another way and found some code to it like `e.target.files[0]` but it is throwing an error while doing do. I tried logging the `e` object and it has all other values like name, size, file type etc.

So my problem is how can I get the absolute file path.

```
 <Form.Input                                  
      type="file"
      onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
 />
```

```
handleChange(e) {
       console.log(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: @Seblor I am using that. I got `fakepath` when I used `value`

Comment: Sorry about that, I misread. Be careful of typos, you wrote `e.targe.file` (though you wrote it correctly in the code snippet)

Comment: Please try e.target.files instead of e.targe.file

Comment: Refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290796/how-get-get-file-name-in-file-chooser-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290796/how-get-get-file-name-in-file-chooser-in-react)

Comment: @gautamits I am using `files`

Comment: Would you give us the `Form.Input` component?

Comment: @laruiss it is a semantic ui component

Comment: `e.target.files[0].name` or `e.target.name` would work